# Select by first index of multiindex (Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with index (a, b)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3, 1], 'b' : [11, 11, 11, -7], 'val' : [10, 19, 24, 12]})
df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)
```

```
a | b  | val
1 | 11 | 10
2 | 11 | 19
3 | 11 | 24
1 | -7 | 12
```

I'd like to pick from it only the rows with b == 11.

I've tried

```
df[df.index[1] == 11]
```

> KeyError: False

It failed. Could you help?

Comment: You can use `xs`. Please check: `df.xs(11, level=1)`

Comment: That's the solution)

@shubham-sharma, could you post it so I can accept it?

Comment: @Gooselt I think this question might be a duplicate so I'll pass on adding an answer but anyways thanks!

Comment: There is an alternative with `loc` to keep the second level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options to pick the rows with `b==11`.

1. As suggested by @ShubhamSharma, you can use `xs` but you lost the level `b`:

```
>>> df.xs(11, level=1)
   val
a     
1   10
2   19
3   24
```

2. You can also use `loc` and `pd.IndexSlice` if you want to keep the level:

```
>>> df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 11], :]
      val
a b      
1 11   10
2 11   19
3 11   24
```